# getJson().done() is not working for remote host

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, getjson

I am working on a mobile application using phonegap + html5 + JS + CSS. For this app i need to load a big JSON (200-500kb in size) file from remotehost like "www.mysite.com/file.json".

Here's the code from index.html file that i tried to run from localhost.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myAPI = "http://www.mysite.com/file.json?callback=?"; //for this one .done() does not execute
      // var myAPI = "file.json"  //but for this one .done() executes
    var json = $.getJSON( myAPI, {
        format: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {    
            /*for remote link nothing inside this done() executes but works for local link*/
            $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
            $("#someDiv").append("<div>"+item.id+" "+item.name+"</div>")
            })
        });

</script>
```

I used jquery getJson() and then done() to display loaded json data after loading complete. But the only time done() executes when i put file.json file inside local directory. When using remote link done() does not execute. I checked it using chrome dev-tool breakpoint. There is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and file.json is properly loaded which i can assure from devtool's Network(file.json loading time) and Source(file.json shows in www.mysite.com folder) tab.

Any suggestion how should i load json file from remote host using jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your .json file being processed by the server and converted to jsonp? if not, then your service isn't returning valid jsonp. JSON != JSONP

Comment: Does it work without the callback parameter (i.e. `myAPI = "http://www.mysite.com/file.json"`)?

Comment: @bclune no it does not work with out callback. then it cause Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: @KevinB 
.json file is a static file in the server. i did nothing to convert it to jsonp.
sorry i may not understand your question (*noob alert).

Comment: Then, this request is not going to work unless you modify the json file to contain proper jsonp, for example, `jsonpCallback(thejsonhere)` you wold then simply create a global function `window.jsonpCallback = function(json) { console.log(json);};` and then request the script `$.getScript("http://www.mysite.com/file.json")`

Comment: Hello can display the json file content out here

Comment: @KevinB i could not understand your comment. 
all i need a ajax tutorial where i can load file for phonegap application (from app to remote server).

Comment: what i'm saying is your request isn't possible without either returning the json from a server-side script that sets the correct CORS headers, or modifying the file to include the callback to make it valid JSONP